# To make last EditorGUILayout of EditorWindow fill the remaining space?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

By default all `EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal()` and `EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical()` groups  fill all available parent width (or EditorWindow width). Even just vertical groups. But at the same time `height` is always 0 (if there's no elements in there, otherwise the width will be equal to total inner elements height).

What should I do to force fill all available or remaining height for the element groups?

What should I do to make fill space evenly?

---

What do I have now:

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(); {
//          EditorGUILayout.TextField("Label", "Text");
} EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
 containerRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();

var containerRectVertical = Rect.zero;
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(); {
    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(); {

    } EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

    containerRectVertical = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();         
} EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();  
var containerRect2 = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();

Debug.Log($"winSize: {position.width}x{position.height}, horizSectonSize: {containerRect.width}x{containerRect.height}, 2: {containerRect2.width}x{containerRect2.height}" +
              $", containerRectVertical: {containerRectVertical.width}x{containerRectVertical.height}");
```

Output:

```
winSize: 446x192, horizSectonSize: 447x0, 2: 447x0, containerRectVertical: 447x0
```

Want:

```
winSize: 446x192, horizSectonSize: 447x96, 2: 447x96, containerRectVertical: 447x96
```

or

```
winSize: 446x192, horizSectonSize: 447x192, 2: 447x0, containerRectVertical: 447x192
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
```

For example with horizontal layout with following code

```
GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
GUILayout.Label("left");
GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
GUILayout.Label("right");
GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

you get this:

[image]

Same thing works for vertical groups.

Also see more detailed options here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayoutOption.html

Available hints are:

GUILayout.Width, GUILayout.Height, GUILayout.MinWidth, GUILayout.MaxWidth, GUILayout.MinHeight, GUILayout.MaxHeight, GUILayout.ExpandWidth, GUILayout.ExpandHeight.

You can create your GUILayoutOption[] options once (in OnEnable) and re-use it with each editor repaint to gain some performance

Comment: `GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true), GUILayout.ExpandHeight(true)` -- it helped